# Can't log in with a valid password using Authlogic and Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic

We support a bit of an unusual scheme.  We don't require a password on User creation, and use password_resets to add a password to the user later, on demand.  The problem is, once a password is created, the console indicates the password is valid:

`user.valid_password? 'test'

=> true`

but in my UserSessions controller, @user_session.save returns false using the same password.  What am I not seeing?

Kimball

UPDATE:

Providing more details, here is the output when saving the new password:

`Processing PasswordResetsController#update (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-01-31 14:01:12) [PUT]
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Update password", "action"=>"update", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"PQD4+eIREKBfHR3/fleWuQSEtZd7RIvl7khSYo5eXe0=", "id"=>"v3iWW5eD9P9frbEQDvxp", "controller"=>"password_resets", "user"=>{"password"=>"johnwayne"}}`

The applicable SQL is:

`UPDATE users SET updated_at = '2011-01-31 22:01:12',

 crypted_password = 'blah',

 perishable_token = 'blah',

 password_salt = 'blah',

 persistence_token = 'blah'

 WHERE id = 580

I don't see an error per se, @user_session.save just returns false, as if the password didn't match.

I skip validating passwords in the User model:

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_authentic do |c|

    c.validate_password_field = false

  end


Here's the simplified controller code:

  def create

    logger.info("SAVED SESSION? #{@user_session.save}")

end


which outputs:


Processing UserSessionsController#create (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-01-31 14:16:59) [POST]

  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Login", "user_session"=>{"remember_me"=>"0", "password"=>"johnwayne", "email"=>"test@email.com"}, "action"=>"create", "authenticity_token"=>"PQD4+eIREKBfHR3/fleWuQSEtZd7RIvl7khSYo5eXe0=", "controller"=>"user_sessions"}

  User Columns (2.2ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM users

  User Load (3.7ms)   SELECT * FROM users WHERE (users.email = 'test@email.com') ORDER BY email ASC LIMIT 1

SAVED SESSION? false

  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM users WHERE (users.email = 'test@email.com') ORDER BY email ASC LIMIT 1

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/login


Lastly, the console indicates that the new password is valid:


$ u.valid_password? 'johnwayne'

 => true`

Would love to do it all in the console, is there a way to load UserSession controller and call methods directly?

Kimball

Comment: When you are saving the user again, what fields are you setting?

Comment: Is there a password confirmation that you need to provide as well?  If not, can you please include the validation error message from the user model?

Comment: authlogic requires a password_confirmation field when adding the User, but not for authentication. I agree with @Pan Thomakos, post the error message, please.

Comment: edited my question with more detail, thank you for taking a look!  The password_confirmation is a great point, one thing I forgot to mention is that users that created accounts with a password can successfully change their passwords and log in with it.

Comment: In answer to your last point: http://www.tatvartha.com/2009/09/working-with-authlogic-in-scriptconsole/

Answer (score 2):

on your object you are saving, call after save u.errors.full_messages.inspect  What is the output of this.  also do  u.valid?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had an 'active' attribute on my User model that needs to be true to allow logins. I found the problem by using @zetitic's link to try to create a UserSession.  The errors.full_messages on the created UserSession object showed the error.  Many thanks to everyone for your help!  I do wish I'd seen the error in the log, but that's another matter..

Answer (score 1):

Users will also be denied access if their failed_login_count is over 50, per [Authlogic::Session::BruteForceProtection](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/Authlogic/Session/BruteForceProtection/Config).